# How to retrieve selected Checkbox values for dynamic Treeview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, treeview

I have a `gridview` where I'm generating controls dynamically to the columns in `RowCreated` event. And one of my control is `Treeview` and I'm generating the control with checkboxes as

```
  TreeView TreeView1 = new TreeView();
  TreeView1.ID = "tvProducts";
  TreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
  TreeView1.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.All;
  BindData();
  e.Row.Cells[rowIndex].Controls.Add(TreeView1);
```

Now,I'm checking few nodes and calling the below method

```
TreeView val =   (TreeView)row.FindControl("tvtvProducts");
foreach (TreeNode node in val.CheckedNodes)
{
}
```

The checked nodes count is always `zero`. So,it doesnot loop.
What should be done to get the checked nodes